# how do i search for a row in a csv in python and putting it in a different file using this code:

Tags: python, csv

```
import re
import csv

with open('a.csv','r') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    dict2 = {row[0]: row[1:] for row in r}

with open('b.csv', 'r') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    dict1 = {row[0]: row[1:] for row in r}

fine = {k: (dict1[k], dict2[k]) for k in set(dict1).intersection(dict2)}

with open('c.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    for value in fine.items():
        w.writerow(value)
```

please help, I cant find how to input it into another csv, I am doing this for school so please can you help me solve the way to actually change it so that is searches for a row that includes certain words in the first two csv s

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do. That code is writing to c.csv all the lines that have the same value as the first field in both a.csv and b.csv.   Do you want to only write to c.csv some given line? Instead that all of them?

Answer (score 0):

One of those?

```py
for value in fine.items()::
    unpacked_value = [elem for lst in value for elem in lst]
    w.writerow(unpacked_value)
```

```py
for value in fine:
    for row in fine[value]:
        w.writerow((value, row))
```